# T4 + `\|` gives strange `\mathaccent` error

Tags: math-mode, errors, font-encodings

The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T4]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[OT4]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{polski}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\def\re{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
\item
Sprawdzić, czy są normami na $\re^2$:
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
\item
$\|(x_1,x_2)\|=(|x_1|^{1/2}+|x_2|^{1/2})^2$,
\item
$\|(x_1,x_2)\|=|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2$,
\item
$\|(x_1,x_2)\|=
\begin{cases}
\|(x_1,x_2)\|_2,&\text{gdy $x_1x_2>0$},\\ %this is line 27
\|(x_1,x_2)\|_1,&\text{gdy $x_1x_2\leq0$}.
\end{cases}
$
\end{enumerate}
\item
Niech $\|{}.{}\|_1$ i $\|{}.{}\|_2$ będą dowolnymi (nie tylko $l_2^p$, jak w poprzednim przykładzie)  normami. Czy jest normą $\frac12(\|{}.{}\|_1+\|{}.{}\|_2)$?
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

gives the error message

```
! Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode.
\add@accent ...@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 
                                              #1 #2\egroup \spacefactor ...
l.27 \|
   (x_1,x_2)\|_2,&\text{gdy $x_1x_2>0$},\\ %this is line 27
?
```

After replacing `\usepackage[T4]{fontenc}` by one of commented now lines below all compiles without errors. Please observe also that `\|` is used earlier in the code without any problem.

I know how to correct the file to obtain an opening norm (`\|`), but my question is: what is the source of this strange behaviour?

Comment: What's the reason for using T4 (African languages)? While OT4 was meant for Polish, T4 isn't; Polish is covered by T1.

Comment: @egreg This was an accidental mistype, leading to strange result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `t4enc.def` does

```
\def\|{\ifmmode\Vert\else\I\fi}% single universal accent
```

which misses an important bit, that is, an initial `\relax`. With recent versions of LaTeX it's better to do a `\protected` definition.

What happens is that `\|` in `cases` is examined and expanded in order to see whether it starts with `\omit` (a standard behavior in tables), *before* entering math mode for the current cell, so the false branch is followed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % I can't use cp1250
\usepackage[T4]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[OT4]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{polski}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newcommand\re{\mathbb{R}}

% fix the bad definition in t4enc.def
%\def\|{\relax\ifmmode\Vert\else\I\fi}% single universal accent
\protected\def\|{\ifmmode\Vert\else\I\fi}% single universal accent

\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
\item
Sprawdzić, czy są normami na $\re^2$:
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
\item
$\|(x_1,x_2)\|=(|x_1|^{1/2}+|x_2|^{1/2})^2$,
\item
$\|(x_1,x_2)\|=|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2$,
\item
$\|(x_1,x_2)\|=
\begin{cases}
\|(x_1,x_2)\|_2,&\text{gdy $x_1x_2>0$},\\ %this is line 27
\|(x_1,x_2)\|_1,&\text{gdy $x_1x_2\leq0$}.
\end{cases}
$
\end{enumerate}
\item
Niech $\|{}.{}\|_1$ i $\|{}.{}\|_2$ będą dowolnymi (nie tylko $l_2^p$, jak w poprzednim przykładzie)  normami. Czy jest normą $\frac12(\|{}.{}\|_1+\|{}.{}\|_2)$?
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Important note

The T4 encoding is ***not*** for the Polish language; it doesn't correspond in any way to OT4 (except for the number). The Polish language is fully covered by the T1 encoding.

What's T4 for? For African languages.

Here's the same with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (and removing the redefinition for `\|`.

[image]

Can you spot a difference? Yes, T4 encoded fonts are only available in the `cmr` family and they are *bitmap only*.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the example to make it a bit more minimal, a workaround is to save the definition of `\|` and restore it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\let\oldmacro\|
\usepackage[T4]{fontenc}
\let\|\oldmacro

\usepackage{amsmath}%,amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\|(x_1,x_2)\|=
\begin{cases}
  \|(x_1,x_2)\|_2,&\text{gdy $x_1x_2>0$},\\ %this is line 27
\end{cases}
$
\end{document}
```

The problem is that `T4.def` changes the definition of `\|` so that it is no longer specified as a delimiter:

```
\delimiter "026B30D .
```

is the original definition, before loading the encoding, while afterwards it is

```
\ifmmode \Vert \else \I \fi
```

I don't understand the details well enough to give a thorough explanation of why this causes the particular problem it does, but TeX does not like the `\ifmmode` here. (`\Vert` itself works OK. Or, at least, without error.)

Comment: Thank you for the step to understanding. However it is still unclear, why in different places in math mode `\|` behaves differently.

Comment: That's just how the `cases` environment is defined, isn't it? It is checking the next thing and it only expects things of certain kinds. `\ifmmode` isn't one of them, I think. See `amsmath.sty` and `amsgen.sty` for the relevant checks being done here.